# Is there a way to count the number inputs from the user in C with scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following block of code:

```
printf("Enter size:\n");
scanf("%d",&size);
```

My question is, how do I ensure that users only input one integer? I want the program to exit if they input an incorrect number of integers.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Do you mean input only one integer on a line, or input only one integer in the entire standard input stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of conversions and assignments, so

```
scanf( "%d", &size );
```

will return `1` if you successfully read an integer input (see below), `0` if you entered something that was not an integer (that is, the first non-whitespace character you type isn't a decimal digit), or `EOF` if there was an error on the input stream.

Here's where you need to be careful, though - the `%d` conversion specifier will skip leading whitespace, then read decimal digits until it sees *any* non-digit character (not just whitespace).  So if you enter something like `"12w45"`, `scanf` will convert and assign the `12` to `size` and return `1` to indicate success, even though you *probably* want to reject the entire input.

You either need to check the character immediately following your input like so:

```
int tmp;
char chk;

int n = 0;

if ( (n = scanf( "%d%c", &tmp, &chk )) == 2 ) // up to 2 conversions and assignments
{
  if ( isspace( chk ) ) // only thing following your input is whitespace
    size = tmp;
  else
    fprintf( stderr, "non-numeric character in input, try again\n" );
}
else if ( n == 1 ) // only thing following input was EOF
{
  size = tmp;
}
else if ( n == 0 ) // first non-whitespace character was not a digit
{
  fprintf( stderr, "non-numeric character in input, try again\n" );
}
else
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Error on input stream\n" );
}
```

*or* you will need to use something other than `scanf` for validating input.  You'd probably be better off reading the input as text using `fgets`, then converting that text using `strtol` (for integer types) or `strtod` (for floating point types) - they give you an opportunity to check for malformed input.  Example:

```
char inbuf[12]; // up to 10 decimal digits plus sign and terminator
int size;
int tmp;
char *chk; // will point to the first character *not* converted by strtol

if ( fgets( inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stdin ) ) // read input as text
{
  tmp = strtol( inbuf, &chk, 10 ); // convert string to integer
  if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "non-numeric character in input, try again\n" );
  }
  else
  {
    size = tmp;
  }
}
else
{
  fprintf( stderr, "error on input\n" );
}
```